MKLocalSearchCompleter not showing address consistently
The SwiftUI code below returns locations & addresses as the user types. The code below works great for most restaurants, Say Pino's Pizza, El Pelon Taqueria. But if I try something like Shake Shack I get a bunch of locations but with no addresses. Any thoughts on fixing this? Thanks!
import Foundation
import MapKit

@Observable
class LocationSearcher: NSObject, ObservableObject, MKLocalSearchCompleterDelegate {
    private(set) var searchResults: [MKLocalSearchCompletion] = [] // Result of our search
    
    // This object takes in text to search on and returns the results in the value above
    private let completer = MKLocalSearchCompleter()
    
    var error: Error?
    
    // By adding the 'delegate' below, we're saying that 'completer' above can be automatically called by iOS when tasks need to be performed
    override init() {
        super.init()
        completer.delegate = self
    }
    
    // Adds typed text to the "competer" for processing & returning results
    func updateSearchText(_ text: String) {
        if text.isEmpty {
            searchResults = []
        }
        completer.queryFragment = text
    }
}

import SwiftUI

struct LocationSearchView: View {
    @Binding var selectedLocation: LocationResult?
    @State private var searchText: String = ""
    @StateObject private var searcher = LocationSearcher()
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List(searcher.searchResults, id: \.self) { result in
                VStack (alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(result.title)
                    Text(result.subtitle)
                        .font(.caption)
                        .foregroundStyle(.secondary)
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Location Search")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        }
        .searchable(text: $searchText)
        .autocorrectionDisabled()
        .onChange(of: searchText) {
            searcher.updateSearchText(searchText)
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    LocationSearchView(selectedLocation: .constant(nil))

